# jquery library in conflict with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page using jquery and jquery mobile. In this same page, I have a link that points to another portion of the same page (see http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/how-do-i-make-links-to-different-sections-of-the-same-page/). Now when I click on that link, it doesnt go anywhere. Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/sCsSN/.
This is suppose to work no? Also if I remove one of the libraries, this works but if I keep both of them, it doesnt work. Anyone has any suggestions on how can I go about into doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you expecting it to go?

Comment: When you click on the link, you should go to "testing" which is located in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jQuery-Mobile [Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) using hashs to navigate isn't supported

> Since we use the URL hash to preserve Back button behavior, using page
>   anchors to jump down to a position on the page isn't supported by
>   using the traditional anchor link (#foo). Use the [silentScroll](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html) method
>   to scroll to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event
>   listeners. You can pass in a yPos arguments to scroll to that Y
>   location.

Here's the silentScroll method example from the doc's

```
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

You might want to also take a look at [this forum thread](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-anchor-linking) in the JQM forum about the same subject.